# How to achieve Github organization and repository policy-as-code/infrastructure-as-code?

Tags: github, github-api, infrastructure

The motivation is that we're starting to feel policy drift and maintenance headaches because of non-programmable (or non-codified) repository and or organization settings.
For example we might need to remove a specific team from accessing 50/100 repos. Or we might need to enable a new github feature (like auto-merge) for all of those repos. Sometimes the codeowner forgets to enable linear history and a contributor merge-commits.

At scale, clicking buttons doesn't work.

The best solution I can come up with is a script that makes idempotent calls to the [Github API](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.2/rest). Another partial solution might be to start using monorepos.
Is there any better way to solve the problem I'm facing?

Comment: Interesting question because the github API seems to have different features than the Web UI (tempted to say "subset" but not 100% sure). An example I had was trying to set branch rules on a set of repos in an organisation where we use branches of the style release-01, release-02 etc - the web ui supports wildcards but the API does not, so any new release-* branches have to be setup additionally, or at least that is my experience. The frequent practice, that the UI is itself using the restful api does not seem to apply.

Comment: This implies there's basically no solution, and Github (which is supposed to be _for developers and power users_) has just as bad vendor lock-in as your average mobile app. I hope a solution will come by soon, one that's perhaps more generic, like https://apify.com/ or https://wrapapi.com/ or a bunch of alternatives.

Comment: If you have a choice, you might want to look at gitlab rather than github. I've not tried to get as far as I suspect you want to go, but definitely I can do things in the gitlab API that I apparently can't in github. Given your report, I suspect this is not an option, but it might be for some other reading this.